# Hadoop 2.6 and 2.7 Apache Terasort on 500GB or 1TB

Tags: apache, hadoop, default, reducers

When running a map and when reducers start it goes from 0 to 100 failing with:

```
15/05/12 07:21:27 INFO terasort.TeraSort: starting
15/05/12 07:21:27 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop     library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/05/12 07:21:29 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process :    18000

Spent 1514ms computing base-splits.
Spent 109ms computing TeraScheduler splits.
Computing input splits took 1624ms
Sampling 10 splits of 18000
Making 1 from 100000 sampled records
Computing parititions took 315ms
Spent 1941ms computing partitions.
15/05/12 07:21:30 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at    n1/192.168.2.1:8032
15/05/12 07:21:31 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:18000
15/05/12 07:21:31 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1431389162125_0001
15/05/12 07:21:31 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1431389162125_0001
15/05/12 07:21:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://n1:8088/proxy/application_1431389162125_0001/
15/05/12 07:21:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1431389162125_0001
15/05/12 07:21:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1431389162125_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/05/12 07:21:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/05/12 07:21:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 1% reduce 0%
15/05/12 07:22:01 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 2% reduce 0%
15/05/12 07:22:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 3% reduce 0%
15/05/12 07:22:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 4% reduce 0%
15/05/12 07:22:38 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 5% reduce 0%
15/05/12 07:22:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 6% reduce 0%
15/05/12 07:23:02 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 7% reduce 0%
15/05/12 07:23:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 8% reduce 0%
15/05/12 07:23:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 9% reduce 0%
15/05/12 07:23:40 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 10% reduce 0%
15/05/12 07:23:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 11% reduce 0%
15/05/12 07:24:02 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/05/12 07:24:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1431389162125_0001 failed with  state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1431389162125_0001_r_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:0 failedReduces:1
```

This is with the default configuration and fails every time.

Any configuration I insert into the xml I commented out to find this issue but I'm still having issues with the job failing only during the start of reducing.

Answer (score 0):

Yarn handles resource management and also serves batch workloads that can use MapReduce and real-time workloads.

There are memory settings that can be set at the Yarn container level and also at the mapper and reducer level. Memory is requested in increments of the Yarn container size. Mapper and reducer tasks run inside a container.

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb and mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb
```

above parameters describe upper memory limit for the map-reduce task and if memory subscribed by this task exceeds this limit, the corresponding container will be killed.

These parameters determine the maximum amount of memory that can be assigned to mapper and reduce tasks respectively. Let us look at an example: Mapper is bound by an upper limit for memory which is defined in the configuration parameter mapreduce.map.memory.mb.

However, if the value for yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb is greater than this value of mapreduce.map.memory.mb, then the yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb is respected and the containers of that size are given out.

This parameter needs to be set carefully and if not set properly, this could lead to bad performance or OutOfMemory errors.

```
mapreduce.reduce.java.opts and mapreduce.map.java.opts
```

This property value needs to be less than the upper bound for map/reduce task as defined in mapreduce.map.memory.mb/mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb, as it should fit within the memory allocation for the map/reduce task.